# Definite Integral theorem validity :- $\int_{0}^{L} \left( \int_{s}^{L}p(t)\ dt \right) \ ds =\int_{0}^{L} \ p(s) \ ds$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, definite-integrals

Can we write

$\int_{0}^{L} \left( \int_{s}^{L}p(t)\ dt \right) \ ds =\int_{0}^{L} \ p(s)    \ ds\tag 1$  ?

In other words, is this result valid? If so, could you help me to get the  proof it

NB :: function $ p$ is a continues function

Comment: $\int_0^L\int_s^L p(t)dtds=\int_0^L sp(s)ds$

Comment: Could you mention the proof?

Comment: It can be first found using some intuition about geometry and "density" - no proof necessary. But it can be proved using by-parts integration.

Comment: I think it is Fubini’s Theorem  of changing variables as $0\le s\le L$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that will not hold in general.  For example, suppose $p(s) = 1$ is the constant function.  Then the left hand side is 
$$
\int_0^L \left(\int_s^L dt\right) ds = \int_0^L (L-s) ds = \left.(Ls - \frac{1}{2}s^2)\right\vert_{s=0}^{s=L} = \frac{1}{2}L^2
$$
but the right hand side is
$$
\int_0^L ds = L.
$$

Comment: It is not a constant function..  Assume p(s) is the equation of continuous curve

Comment: constant function is a continues function.it is not valid generally,althugh you can find a special function satisfying it.